Flutter - The UI does not change when the value specified with Flutter Observer is updated
I'm developing a movie application with Flutter. Movies are shown on the page called "Movies". These movies are shown in categories. The user selects a category via TabBar and movies belonging to the selected category are displayed in TabBarView.
But there is a problem. TabBarView is not automatically updated when the user changes the default category via TabBar. It is updated when you hot reload.
My codes:
../movies/view/movies_view.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/core/base/view/base_widget.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/core/extension/context_extension.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/core/extension/theme_extension.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/core/models/movie_model.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/ui/shared/layout/base_body.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/ui/shared/widget/gradient_widget.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/ui/views/menu/movies/view_model/movies_view_model.dart';

part 'widgets/header_title.dart';
part 'widgets/search_text_form_field.dart';
part 'widgets/tabbar.dart';
part 'widgets/tabbar_view.dart';
part 'widgets/movie_card.dart';

class MoviesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MoviesView({super.key});

  @override
  _MoviesViewState createState() => _MoviesViewState();
}

class _MoviesViewState extends State<MoviesView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<MoviesViewModel>(
      viewModel: MoviesViewModel(),
      onModelReady: (MoviesViewModel model) {
        model.setContext(context);
        model.init();
        model.initTabController(this);
      },
      onPageBuilder: (context, viewModel) => BaseBody(
        padding: true,
        paddingValue: context.horizontalPaddingMedium,
        topPadding: true,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            const BuildHeaderTitle(),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(child: context.emptySizedHeightBoxLow3x),
            const BuildSearchTextFormField(),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(child: context.emptySizedHeightBoxLow3x),
            Observer(
              builder: (_) {
                return BuildTabBar(
                  viewModel: viewModel,
                );
              },
            ),
            Observer(
              builder: (_) => BuildTabBarView(
                viewModel: viewModel,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

../movies/view_model/movies_view_model.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/core/base/model/base_view_model.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/core/constants/navigation/navigation_constants.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/core/models/movie_model.dart';

part 'movies_view_model.g.dart';

class MoviesViewModel = _MoviesViewModel with _$MoviesViewModel;

abstract class _MoviesViewModel extends BaseViewModel with Store {
  @observable
  List<MovieModel> _movies = [];
  @computed
  List<MovieModel> get movies => _movies;

  @observable
  List<Tab> _tabs = [
    const Tab(text: "Action"),
    const Tab(text: "Adventure"),
    const Tab(text: "Documentary"),
    const Tab(text: "Animation"),
    const Tab(text: "Biography"),
    const Tab(text: "Comedy"),
    const Tab(text: "Crime"),
  ];
  @computed
  List<Tab> get tabs => _tabs;

  @observable
  int _selectedTabIndex = 0;
  @computed
  int get selectedTabIndex => _selectedTabIndex;
  @observable
  late TabController _tabController;
  @computed
  TabController get tabController => _tabController;

  @override
  void setContext(context) => viewModelContext = context;

  @override
  void init() {
    _movies = [
      MovieModel(
        id: "1",
        title: "Spider-Man",
        imageUrl:
            "https://image.api.playstation.com/vulcan/ap/rnd/202306/1219/60eca3ac155247e21850c7d075d01ebf0f3f5dbf19ccd2a1.jpg",
        year: "2002",
        category: "Action",
      ),
      MovieModel(
        id: "2",
        title: "Sherlock Holmes",
        imageUrl:
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS125VQdlr9k6BhIBtGXdJAyjoOlviGVrAXuQ&s",
        year: "2009",
        category: "Action",
      ),
      MovieModel(
        id: "3",
        title: "The Dark Knight",
        imageUrl:
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS3ekE6Hhz9gvIbiFSUPxt-FyAh4zXTXX0bjQ&s",
        year: "2008",
        category: "Action",
      ),
      // ...
    ];
  }

  @action
  void initTabController(TickerProvider vsync) {
    _tabController = TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: vsync);
    tabController.addListener(() {
      _selectedTabIndex = tabController.index;
    });
  }

  @action
  void navigateToMovieDetail(MovieModel movieModel) {
    navigationService.navigateToPage(
        path: NavigationConstants.MOVIE_DETAIL, data: movieModel);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
  }
}

../movies/view/widgets/tabbar.dart:
part of '../movies_view.dart';

class BuildTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final MoviesViewModel viewModel;

  const BuildTabBar({super.key, required this.viewModel});

  @override
  State<BuildTabBar> createState() => BuildTabBarState();
}

class BuildTabBarState extends State<BuildTabBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Observer(
      builder: (_) {
        return SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
            TabBar(
              controller: widget.viewModel.tabController,
              tabs: widget.viewModel.tabs
                  .map(
                    (e) => MyGradientWidget(
                      gradient: widget.viewModel.tabController.index ==
                              widget.viewModel.tabs.indexOf(e)
                          ? context.colors.tomatoToLightTomatoLinearGradient
                          : null,
                      child: e,
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
              tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
              isScrollable: true,
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 0,
                right: context.horizontalPaddingMedium.right,
              ),
              labelStyle: context.textTheme.h5,
              unselectedLabelStyle: context.textTheme.h5,
              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  width: 3,
                  color: context.colors.primaryContainer,
                ),
                insets: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 0,
                  right: 38,
                ),
              ),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              dividerColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0), // remove divider
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      color: context.colors.background,
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

../movies/view/widgets/tabbar_view.dart:
part of "../movies_view.dart";

class BuildTabBarView extends StatefulWidget {
  final MoviesViewModel viewModel;

  BuildTabBarView({required this.viewModel});

  @override
  State<BuildTabBarView> createState() => BuildTabBarViewState();
}

class BuildTabBarViewState extends State<BuildTabBarView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final moviesForCategory = widget.viewModel.movies
        .where((element) =>
            element.category == widget.viewModel.tabs[widget.viewModel.tabController.index].text)
        .toList();

    return SliverPadding(
      padding: context.verticalPaddingNormal,
      sliver: moviesForCategory.isEmpty
          ? SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "No movie found",
                  style: context.textTheme.h5,
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Observer(
              builder: (_) {
                return SliverGrid.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: context.mediumValueW,
                    mainAxisSpacing: context.lowValueH,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.6,
                  ),
                  itemCount: moviesForCategory.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final movie = moviesForCategory[index];
                    return MovieCard(
                      movie: movie,
                      viewModel: widget.viewModel,
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}

How can I solve the problem? Thank you in advance for your help, I am grateful.

